# How to calculate percent change compared to the beginning value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a `DataFrame` and need to calculate percent change compared to the beginning of the year by companies. Is there any way to use `pct_change()` or other method to perform this task? Thanks!

`df` looks like

```
security    date        price
IBM         1/1/2016    100
IBM         1/2/2016    102
IBM         1/3/2016    108
AAPL        1/1/2016    1000
AAPL        1/2/2016    980
AAPL        1/3/2016    1050
AAPL        1/4/2016    1070
```

results I want

```
security    date        price   change
IBM         1/1/2016    100     NA
IBM         1/2/2016    102     2%
IBM         1/3/2016    108     8%
AAPL        1/1/2016    1000    NA
AAPL        1/2/2016    980     -2%
AAPL        1/3/2016    1050    5%
AAPL        1/4/2016    1070    7%
```

Comment: First split your data frame and then use pct_change() to calculate the percent change for each date.

Comment: If I do df.groupby('security')['price'].pct_change(), that will give me the percent change compare to the previous days. However, what I need is percent change compare to 100 and 1000. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for an [`expanding_window`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions) version of `pct_change()`. This doesn't exist out of the box AFAIK, but you could roll your own:

```
df.groupby('security')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).subtract(1).mul(100))
```

Comment: I like your one liner! I think this "compared to the beginning" could be a nice feature to have for `pct_change()`

Comment: Either that or adding an `expanding_pct_change()` to the expanding window functions mentioned in the docs. There is also `expanding_apply`, by the way, see Cookbook: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but I faced a similar problem and I'd like to share my solution with you, in case it's helpful for anybody.

## TL; DR

```
def get_variation(values: pd.Series) -> np.float64:
    base = values.iloc[0]  # first element in window iteration
    current = values.iloc[-1]  # last element in window iteration

    return (current - base) / base if base else 0  # avoid ZeroDivisionError

variations = df.groupby('security')['price'].expanding(min_periods=2).apply(get_variation)
df = df.assign(change=variations.droplevel(0))
```

|  | security | date | price | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IBM | 1/1/2016 | 100 | NaN |
| 1 | IBM | 1/2/2016 | 102 | 0.02 |
| 2 | IBM | 1/3/2016 | 108 | 0.08 |
| 3 | AAPL | 1/1/2016 | 1000 | NaN |
| 4 | AAPL | 1/2/2016 | 980 | -0.02 |
| 5 | AAPL | 1/3/2016 | 1050 | 0.05 |
| 6 | AAPL | 1/4/2016 | 1070 | 0.07 |

You can do what you are asking by:

1. defining your own variation function,
2. grouping `pd.DataFrame` by `security` column,
3. using an *expanding* window operation on the resulting `price` column,
4. calling `apply` on the expanding window operation and passing your custom variation function defined in step 1 as argument,
5. dropping outer index of resulting series,
6. assigning previous result to original `pd.DataFrame`.

Optionally, you can replace the expanding window operation in step 3 with a *rolling* window operation by calling `.rolling(window=2, min_periods=2)`, to get a step-by-step variation on each security price. `window=2` defines the size of the window in order to return two elements on each iteration and `min_periods=2` sets the minimum data needed for calculations (will result in `NaN`, if else).

## Step by step

#### 1. Defining your own variation function

Your variation function should accept a `pd.Series` as argument and use the first and last items in the collection to calculate the variation. Here, I'm using a standard variation function used in finance to calculate interest rates. The last line has an `if/else` statement to avoid `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
def get_variation(values: pd.Series) -> np.float64:
    base = values.iloc[0]
    current = values.iloc[-1]

    return (current - base) / base if base else 0
```

#### 2. Grouping `pd.DataFrame` by `security` column

Next, you should call [`.groupby('security')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) to group `pd.DataFrame` by `security` column, in order to prepare data for group calculations.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('security')
```

|  |  | security | date | price | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| security |  |  |  |  |  |
| AAPL | 3 | AAPL | 1/1/2016 | 1000 | NaN |
|  | 4 | AAPL | 1/2/2016 | 980 | -0.02 |
|  | 5 | AAPL | 1/3/2016 | 1050 | 0.05 |
|  | 6 | AAPL | 1/4/2016 | 1070 | 0.07 |
| IBM | 0 | IBM | 1/1/2016 | 100 | NaN |
|  | 1 | IBM | 1/2/2016 | 102 | 0.02 |
|  | 2 | IBM | 1/3/2016 | 108 | 0.08 |

#### 3. Using a expanding window operation on the resulting `price` column

Next, you should use a expanding window operation by calling [`.expanding(min_periods=2)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html#pandas-series-expanding) on the price groups. This will iterate each `price` group and get you all data up to the current iteration as a `pd.Series`. You call `.expanding(min_periods=n)` to set `n` as the minimum number of observations required to return a value on each iteration (or `Nan`, if else). In your case, given that you required `NaN` on the first record as it is not compared to anything else, you should pass `min_periods=2`; if you rather have `0` as a result instead, pass `min_periods=1`.

```
windows = grouped_df['price'].expanding(min_periods=2)
```

#### 4. Calling `apply` on the expanding window operation and passing your custom variation function defined in step 1 as argument

Calling [`.apply(get_variation)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html?highlight=window%20functions#pandas-core-window-expanding-expanding-apply) will apply your custom variation formula to each resulting window and return the result.

```
grouped_variations = windows.apply(get_variation)
```

| security |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 3 | NaN |
|  | 4 | -0.02 |
|  | 5 | 0.05 |
|  | 6 | 0.07 |
| IBM | 0 | NaN |
|  | 1 | 0.02 |
|  | 2 | 0.08 |

#### 5. Dropping outer index of resulting series

As you can see on .4, data is presented with a multi-index. We get rid of the outer index level ('AAPL', 'IBM') by calling [`.droplevel(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html#pandas-series-droplevel), to prepare the data for merging it correctly into the original dataframe.

```
variations = grouped_variations.droplevel(0)
```

#### 6. Assigning previous result to original `pd.DataFrame`

Finally, we assign the price variations into the original dataframe by calling [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign). Data will be joined into the destination on its index.

```
df = df.assign(change=variations)
```

|  | security | date | price | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IBM | 1/1/2016 | 100 | NaN |
| 1 | IBM | 1/2/2016 | 102 | 0.02 |
| 2 | IBM | 1/3/2016 | 108 | 0.08 |
| 3 | AAPL | 1/1/2016 | 1000 | NaN |
| 4 | AAPL | 1/2/2016 | 980 | -0.02 |
| 5 | AAPL | 1/3/2016 | 1050 | 0.05 |
| 6 | AAPL | 1/4/2016 | 1070 | 0.07 |

Comment: My only regret is that I have but one upvote to give for this very thorough explanation

Answer (score 2):

This works, assuming you're already ordered by date within each possible grouping.

```
def pct_change(df):
    df['pct'] = 100 * (1 - df.iloc[0].price / df.price)
    return df

df.groupby('security').apply(pct_change)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but solved it his way:

*(only difference was that the columns would be your company and not the row.)*

for each column of my dataframe I did:

`df[column] = df[column].pct_change().cumsum()`

`pct_change()` calculates the change between now and the last value, and `cumcum()` adds it all together.

Comment: `x.pct_change().cumsum()` for series of 1000, 500, 300 would be equal to [-0.5, -0.9], which is obviously incorrect. cumum will again add pct of previous prices, not of the first price

Comment: but to continue on that idea, for some cases x.pct_change().cumprod().cumsum() might  work (you'll have to set initial value to zero and add one to have cumulative change