# how to construct an index from percentage change time series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the values below

```
array1 = np.array([526.59, 528.88, 536.19, 536.18, 536.18, 534.14, 538.14, 535.44,532.21, 531.94, 531.89, 531.89, 531.23, 529.41, 526.31, 523.67])
```

I convert these into a pandas Series object

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.Series(array1)
```

And compute the percentage change as

```
df = (1+df.pct_change(periods=1))
```

from here, how do i construct an index (base=100)? My desired output should be:

```
0     100.00
1     100.43
2     101.82
3     101.82
4     101.82
5     101.43
6     102.19
7     101.68
8     101.07
9     101.02
10    101.01
11    101.01
12    100.88
13    100.54
14     99.95
15     99.45
```

I can achieve the objective through an iterative (loop) solution, but that may not be a practical solution, if the data depth and breadth is large. Secondly, is there a way in which i can get this done in a single step on multiple columns? thank you all for any guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090498/how-to-calculate-percent-change-compared-to-the-beginning-value-using-pandas

Comment: What's wrong with sipmply `df =  pd.Series(array1)/array1[0]*100` ?

Comment: nothing wrong. its just the lack of creativity:). This solution probably is most simple and efficient. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index (base=100) is the relative change of a series in retation to its first element. So there's no need to take a detour to relative changes and recalculate the index from them when you can get it directly by

```
df = pd.Series(array1)/array1[0]*100
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is still no off-the-shelf `expanding_window` version for pct_change(). You can avoid the for-loop by using `apply`:

```
# generate data
import pandas as pd
series =  pd.Series([526.59, 528.88, 536.19, 536.18, 536.18, 534.14, 538.14, 535.44,532.21, 531.94, 531.89, 531.89, 531.23, 529.41, 526.31, 523.67])

# copmute percentage change with respect to first value
series.apply(lambda x: ((x / series.iloc[0]) - 1) * 100) + 100
```

Output:

```
0     100.000000
1     100.434873
2     101.823050
3     101.821151
4     101.821151
5     101.433753
6     102.193357
7     101.680624
8     101.067244
9     101.015971
10    101.006476
11    101.006476
12    100.881141
13    100.535521
14     99.946828
15     99.445489
dtype: float64
```