# Estimating percentage return in dataframe over whole time period

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, return

i am pretty new to python.
I want to plot stock index return over a long time period. My goal is to have the plot starting at i.e. 100.
[Should look in the end like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3KxD.png)

Found this but didnt really help me because i only have the monthly percentage change, not absolut data.
[how to construct an index from percentage change time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856261/how-to-construct-an-index-from-percentage-change-time-series)

My DF should look like this in the end:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'return_pct':0.01, 'return_cumul':100}, {'return_pct':0.02,'return_cumul':102}, {'return_pct':0.03,'return_cumul':1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print df
```

Basically i want to use the return data of each month and compute the return over the time.
So return_cumulative should return in the first line 102 (=100* (1+0.02)), in the next line the estimation of the previous line times the return of this line 105.6 (=102* (1+0.03)) and so on over the whole time period.

My idea was to iterate over the return data like here
[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

My friend helped me with this code and now i am stuck, because i don't find the mistake:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i > 0:
        df.iloc[i]["return_cumul"] = df.iloc[i-1]["return_cumul"] * (1 + df.iloc[i]["return_pct"]) 
data_df_2.head()
```

Hope you can help me out :)
Maybe i just make my life way to complicated and if you have better/easier solution, i would be happy to find out.

Comment: I know my opinion isn't always popular, but maybe try to solve it without Pandas. Pandas is hard enough actually knowing Python and your problem should be pretty easy to implement just with some basic Python. Just iterate over the list of returns and output it into a second list