# How to do Calculations on a Groupby Dataframe of 2 groupings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of a collection of data and i have it grouped by 2 different groups not sure how to go about doing calculations or even pull the specific cell I'm looking at

```
ZipCode(group1) Year(group2)    Valuex         x2        x3

10001 2012                       1              7        12
      2013                       5              1        13
      2014                       6              8        15

10002 2012                       x              x         x
      2013                       x              x         x
      2014                       x              x         x
```

So I am still learning about DataFrames; I really don't know where to go from here, I can do `.sum()` or `.mean()` but it's not what I'm looking to do.

I'm looking to grab the first and last year of each zip and get the change in percent.

So for `zipcode = 10001` I would want to pull 2014x -2012x/2012x

But for each zipcode, and if left ungrouped the zips repeat in the 100 thousands

this is my actual dataframe:

[image: DF]

Example would be zcta5 00601 Median Home Value change over time would be its 2017 value - its 2012 value divided by 2012 value

Comment: please provide your input dataframe & the expected dataframe, that is much easier to understand

Comment: i was told the code wasnt minimal but this is what the data frame looks like, https://gyazo.com/77ff9a29aafe1cce09e1d7e38fedb917   i am trying to get the change in value for each zip from the first year of collected data to last year of collected data for each row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percent change compared to the beginning value using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090498/how-to-calculate-percent-change-compared-to-the-beginning-value-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to solve this problem *while* `groupby` than *after* `groupby`. However, you can also try:

```
df = df.swaplevel(0,1) 
df.loc[2017].sub(df.loc[2012]).div(df.loc[2012])
```

Comment: yeah cant use swaplevel on groupby frame, but doing it prior to the group by looks something like this (before any calculation) so i didnt know where i would begin in actually getting the first and last year https://gyazo.com/65eea6c1c606de35aab56bd5b3ddcd98

Comment: I tested on my system and I could do `swaplevel` just fine.

Comment: weird i kept getting use .apply() instead error. BUT i took your advice and what i did was i took each year using .query and put it into a df of its own, than i merged and made a seperate df of all the changes